# Looping through array and appending every even item to new array

Tags: ruby

I am trying to loop through an array, adding every other item to a new array.

```
def yes_no(arr)
  i = 0
  new_array = []
  while i != arr.size
    arr.select.each_with_index {|value , index| index.even?}
    new_array << value
    i += 1
  end
  new_array
end
```

The code is supposed to return a new array with values by their order. For:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

it should return:

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 6, 10, 8, 4]
```

The first value of the initial array is always taken. I believe I have the correct logic with my code, but I need some help completing this problem.

Here is another example:

```
 arr = ['this', 'code', 'is', 'right', 'the']
 // returns ['this', 'is', 'the', 'right', 'code']
```

Comment: What is the expected result? Check it one time more, right now its quite unclear.

Comment: Why are you calling this `yes_no`?

Comment: I think it's still unclear how the expected result is obtained. _"adding every other item to a new array"_ sounds as if the result should simply be `[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]`. It's not obvious why those are followed by `2, 6, 10, 8, 4` (in that order).

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how to fix your code, but here's another way to get the expected result:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

new_array = []

until arr.empty?
  new_array << arr.shift
  arr.rotate!
end

new_array
#=> [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 6, 10, 8, 4]
```

Note that `arr` is being modified, you might want to `dup` it.

Comment: Very clever. I think you can omit the argument to `rotate!`.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 oh you're right, I wasn't aware that `rotate` has a default value.